# I am getting "RuntimeError: Working outside of request context." when I implement flask_login

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-login

I am trying to create a web app that run on google app engine. I am trying to implement authentication using Flask-Login. 
When I run the application, I get the error message as mentioned below.

I have installed Flask-Login and all other libraries.

All my third party libraries are in the project folder as seen in the image.
[image]

Let me know if you need any more information here.

Please help me. This is driving me crazy.

**MyServices.py**

```
import os, sys

on_appengine = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')
if on_appengine and os.name == 'nt':
    sys.platform = "Not Windows"
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))

from lib.flask import Flask
from lib.flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app.config')

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

import MyApp

MyApp.register_blueprints(app)
```

**MyApp.py**

```
from app.controllers.auth import auth_bp
from app.controllers.home import home_bp

def register_blueprints(app):
    app.register_blueprint(home_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
```

**home.py**

```
from lib.flask import render_template, Blueprint
home_bp = Blueprint("home", __name__, template_folder='../templates')


@home_bp.route('/')
def Get():
    return render_template('home/home.html')
```

**auth.py**

```
from app.Repository.UserInfoRepository import UserInfoRepository
from lib.flask import render_template, Blueprint, session, request, make_response, redirect, flash
from lib.flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user, logout_user, confirm_login, fresh_login_required
from MyServices import login_manager
auth_bp = Blueprint("auth", __name__, template_folder='../templates')


@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    userInfoRepository = UserInfoRepository()
    user = userInfoRepository.AuthenticateUser(request)
    if user is not None and user.is_authenticated:
        if login_user(user, remember=True):
            flash("Logged in!")
            return render_template('home/home.html', name=current_user)
        else:
            flash("unable to log you in")       
    return render_template('home/home.html')

def IsLoggedIn():
    if not session.has_key('uid'):
        return False
    return session['ip'] == request.remote_addr

@auth_bp.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return render_template('home/home.html')

@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized_callback():
    return redirect('/')

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    if id is None:
        redirect('/')
    userInfoRepository = UserInfoRepository()
    user = userInfoRepository.GetUserByID(id)
    if user.is_active():
        return user
    else:
        return None
```

**Error Message**

```
[2017-09-15 21:11:47,875] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask\app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask\app.py", line 1856, in process_response
    response = handler(response)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 380, in _update_remember_cookie
    if 'remember' in session:
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\werkzeug\local.py", line 379, in <lambda>
    __contains__ = lambda x, i: i in x._get_current_object()
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\myservices\lib\flask\globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to figure out the issue. The issue is in the way I handle third party packages from the lib folder.

I made the lib folder into a package by adding __init__.py. I was calling lib.flask to import flask. However, the flask-login modules import flask instead of lib.flask. That is why when flask-login's modules call session variable, they get it from flask module instead of lib.flask. Thus it is out of context.
The solution is to remove __init__.py from lib folder. Add lib folder in search, what I am already doing it by adding **sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'lib'))**.

If you are using PyCharm, it will show you not found error for import flask. It is OK and ignore the error if your code is working.

Let me know if you have more questions.